# how to use spray library to deal with nested Array in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a nested array written in JSON serialized format, I want to parse it and deal with the items recursively. How can I do with spray?
This is my ideal code. But it did not work.

```
import Array._
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._   

var s = "[1,2,[3,4,5,[6]]]"
var array = JsonParser(s).convertTo[Array[_]]
// error: Cannot find JsonReader or JsonFormat type class for Array[_]
//          JsonParser(s).convertTo[Array[_]]
for (item <- array) {
    item match {
        case x: Int => do some thing
        case y: Array[_] => do some thing recursively
    }
}
```

Comment: Arrays of mixed types are not great for a type-safe language. Best to change the data structure or use a more low-level JSON library (that does not try to type-cast).

Comment: I am new to scala, which JSON library can do this work? @Thilo

Comment: What do you want your resulting type to be?

Comment: @xidui: Take a look at Morgan's answer for how to access the low-level JsValue directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import Array._
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._   

var s = "[1,2,[3,4,5,[6]]]"
var array = JsonParser(s).convertTo[List[JsValue]]

for (item <- array) {
    item match {
        case x: JsNumber => println("this is a number:", x)
        case y: JsArray => println("this is an array:", y)
        case _ => println("xxxxx")
    }
}
```

and here is my printed result:

```
(this is a number:,1)
(this is a number:,2)
(this is an array:,[3,4,5,[6]])
```